# Can mycelles of soap form without grease/oil in the middle?

Tags: water, surface-tension

Does soap form mycelles even if there is **no grease in the water**, like the image below? (Is it even possible to form mycelles **without grease/oil in the middle**)?

[image]

Or do soap molecules stand on their own with both parts **imersed** in water (hydrophilic and hydrophobic) like the image below?

[image]

Comment: This is probably better asked at [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, above a critical concentration called critical micelle concentration (CMC) a surfactant will form micelles spontaneously. It till depend also on the temperature. This is roughly because the reduction in entropy due to aggregation is compensated by the fact that now the surfactants are together and thus "more happy", gaining an energetical benefit from forming micelles. Having a kind of oil will help though.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to decrease entropy in a system? Could you explain this part a bit more?

Comment: A quick version would be: surfactants are freely floating around, so they are sparse. This mean they have a high entropy. If they aggregate together in one micelle, they loose a lot of their entropy (1 micelle has less entropy than 100 surfactants). That is why they don't aggregate *unless* the energy they gain in aggregating (because now their hydrophobic tail is in a water-less environment so it is more happy) is enough to pay the entropy penalty they get from aggregating.

Comment: If your question is "can the system change its entropy" the answer is yes, microscopic systems are *on average* in their state of max entropy and min energy, but they can fluctuate around it. But it takes a lot of math to show it..!

Comment: Interesting!! Those answer my question perfectly. Regarding your last comment, can a system either increase and decrease in entropy (fluctuate), or just increase?

Comment: Energetical benefit means that they effectively **gain** energy by forming micelles or just that they go into a more energetically favorable state?

Comment: A bit of a both, depending on the chemical detail. They might have a gain in geting together because they actually like each other *or* they might vice versa *pay a price* if they are in contact with water. The important thing is that Energy_in_micelle-Energy_in_solution<0 (i.e. lower energy).

Comment: they can both increase and decrease: there could be a fluctuation taking a micelle and dissolving it again *but* the more a state is far away from the "best" configuration, the less probable that state is. However I encourage you to take what I am saying with a grain of salt because all of these can be quantified, there's exception and details etc :)

Comment: Thanks a LOT!! What did you mean here though: “Energy_in_micelle-Energy_in_solution<0 (i.e. lower energy)”.

Comment: The system will go to the lower energy state (minimization of energy). If the energy of the micelle is lower than the energy in solution (and that energy is enough to overcome entropy) then it will form micelles. I might have written it wrong but that is what I mean! Have fun with physics ;)

Comment: @JalfredP there can be disruption of water structure. This would be endothermic but raising entropy. This could in principle partially account for micelles formation.